# How to detect certain gestures?

Tags: android

SO i am building a game in which i want to be able to allow the user to do certain actions based on the gesture on the screen.

For example, the user makes a circle with their finger on the screen and then something will happen.

Or the user makes a triangle and then something happens..

Is there any way to detect this type of gestures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy wrote an awesome post on the topic with source included:
http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/gesture-detection-in-android-part-2-of-2